# bulk/multiple queries that take a long time never finish in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, long-integer

I have created a function in postgres that inserts data into a table. The function receives a string and enters the value into a table after processing it. What I want is to be able to call the function numerous times in pgAdmin instead of running them in batches.

Example:
in pgAdmin i open up my sql query window and type

```
select customfunction('string1');
select customfunction('string2');
           ^
           .
           .
           .
           .
           v
select customfunction('string100000000');
```

When I try to run this it only works when I run about 6000 lines (6000 functions). If i cancel it while it is running it doesnt commit anything (not even the first line). I have to keep cutting them into batches to complete the entire query. How can I achieve this without running them in batches.

I want to copy and paste the whole query and wait till everything is done. Right now the query just runs with no response indefinitely if i run over 10000 lines in a batch. Is there a way postgres can commit each line once it runs that line?

I would also like to know if anyone can determine exactly what line is being processed  while the query is running.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way postgres can commit each line once it runs that line?

It won't do that if auto-commit is enabled - that is the default, too, so... Are you preceding the calls with a begin statement? If so commit before making your calls...

Also, consider preparing the statement or doing what jack suggested.

Comment: i dont understand. how would commit each line in a batch call?

Comment: loop through something like: `begin; select ...; commit;`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried batching your strings to file, importing the file into a table (which I'll call string_table with a single column called string), and trying:

```
select customfunction(string)
from string_table;
```

ETA:  If you want some kind of progress indicator and need to run one select at a time, you could use a DBI in a scripting language to read the strings from either a file or a table,  iterate through the function calls in a loop, and then do a simple console printout with each iteration.